# How to handle potential empty array when accessing by index in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

What's the preferred way to access elements by index in an array in Typescript when the array also can be empty, leading to elements being `undefined`?

I'm coding a simple game in React with Typescript where I have a `game` variable consisting of an array of sets of type `ISet`. In this simplified example, `ISet` has a `score` property in it's interface, which I try to access

```
const game: ISet[] = [];
const currentSet = game[game.length - 1]; // 'currentSet' will be of type 'ISet', although it will be 'undefined' here
console.log(currentSet.score); // No Typescript error, although a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'score' of undefined' error will be thrown when run
```

How can I have Typescript detect `currentSet` potentially being `undefined` here?

I've tried to manually set `currentSet`'s type to

```
const currentSet: ISet | undefined = game[game.length - 1];
```

but that doesn't work, and changing the type declaration to

```
const game: Array<ISet | undefined> = [];
```

allows `undefined` to be added to the array, which is not what I'm after and will lead to problems later on.

I've read through a couple of GitHub issues,
[like this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778), but couldn't find any suggestions on workarounds. Using something like [last from Underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#last) would work, but it seems a bit overkill to a new package to bypass this issue.

Looking forward to some help!

Andreas

Comment: Weird.. unless you have a horribly old version of tslint it should work. Try running `tslint -v` maybe there is a global tslint version installed and that is getting picked up ..

Comment: Which tslint rule do you refer to that would catch this? [no-spare-arrays](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-sparse-arrays/) will not work here. I'm running version 5.13, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/danielnixon/eslint-plugin-total-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution I could come up with was to use [last from lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#last) and adding it as [a separate package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.last). I also added type definitions separately by installing `@types/lodash.last`.

My example case above would end up looking like this:

```
import last from 'lodash.last'

const game: ISet[] = [];
const currentSet = last(game); // 'currentSet' now has a type of 'ISet | undefined' 
console.log(currentSet.score); // Object is possibly 'undefined'. ts(2532)
```

Answer (score 5):

TypeScript > v4.1 has the option [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) which should return `T | undefined` for all unknown index access.

---

You could implement your own `last` and be more accurate in its typing:

```
function last<T>(array: T[]): T | undefined // Explicit type
{
    return array[array.length - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems normal to me, you have an array of `ISet`, but it's just empty right now.  arrays are allowed to be empty, this is how arrays work.

just check to see if the array has any items in it first

```
const game: ISet[] = [];
if (game.length) {
  const currentSet = game[game.length - 1];
  console.log(currentSet.score);
} else {
  console.log("no games!");
}
```

Doing something like `game: (ISet | undefined)[]` might imply that even when populated **any** item in the array might be `undefined` like this:

```
[{score: 4}, {score: 1}, undefined, {score: 5}, undefined, undefined, {score: 10}]
```

which is probably not your intention (I assume).  Doing this might confuses you or other developers in the future.

Comment: The issue here is that there is no **compile time** error.

Comment: Again, I think this is pretty normal.  I assume this exaple is pseudo-code and you probably aren't actually initializing an empty array and then attempting to access index  `-1` on it _(0 length and then subtract 1)_ - Your array in real code probably gets values from something... so it's usually a good idea to ensure that an array has values on it before you try to access it.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the compiler doesn't really keep track of how many items are in the array, that's something that happens at runtime.  If I ran `someArr[9999]` I don't expect the TS compiler to know that my array only has 421 items in it, that's for me to check.

Comment: That this is normal is not the point. You want to catch as many issues as early as possible, and having the compiler return the *obviously correct type* would be great.

Comment: it is, you've set it to be an array of `ISet` objects, so that's what it's returning.  If you access an item in the array that doesn't exist, that's not a compiler issue.

Comment: It's undeniably the case that indexing an array might return undefined. The Typescript compiler is just plain incorrect to assert that indexing an array cannot return undefined. Consider `Map.get()`. The compiler tells me the result may be a value or undefined. Why should the behavior of indexing an array be different? Or is Map.get() incorrect?